# How to Change Text Cursor Color of Text Input Flex 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, textinput

I want to change the blinking text cursor color of Text Input in Flex 4...
How can I change it ?

Is there any way to handle it, or it can be only controlled by Flash Player ???

Comment: You can create custom cursors and change them using the Cursor Manager.   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf613bf-7fff.html or https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/2/25/Creating-a-Custom-Cursor-in-Flex .  What I'm not sure of if is the blinking line inside of a TextInput constitutes a cursor that can be modified using this approach.

Comment: He means text cursor, not mouse cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved this problem,

Actually there was a problem in skinning of text input.
If we set textinput skin's richeditabletext's alpha to 75 or some down value, flash player makes cursor color white itself.

So by increasing that alpha value, I got the cursor color black.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question about this a while ago. I never found a way to update the actual cursor, so I got creative with the solution. My solution was to have two textfields stacked. One input field on top of a dynamic field.

Set the alpha of the input field to 0. Then, add a CHANGE event listener to the input field. In the handler, update the dynamic field and reposition your cursor based on the textWidth.

Not ideal, but it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I change the TextField.textColor = OxFFFFFF, the cursor changes into white as well. Works for my case when I need the same color for the blinking cursor and text.